# Determine the amount of the peaks the traveller passed

Tags: python

It is necessary to determine how many mountains peak according to the data, our traveler exactly crossed. A point is called a mountain peak if the two adjacent points are NOT higher or equal in height to the current point. Extreme points are not considered mountain peaks (starting and ending).
For example:

```
[1,2,3,2,1]
Answer: 1 peak

[1,2,3,3,2,1]
Answer: 0 peak

[1,2,5,6,4,3,4,2,1]
Answer: 2 peaks
```

I am having trouble with comparison of 2 adjacent peaks in a loop, and furthermore  moving through the peaks. Or should I just use any function?

```
peaks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,1,4,5,7,4,3,12,67,85,34,23] #the peak points

for i in peaks:
    if i[0]>i[1][2]  # i stacked here, just dont know the right algorithm
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: this doesn't make much sense: `[3, 1, 3]` should have two peaks, `[3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3]` three, and `[1,2,3,3,2,1]` one!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, you are correct! But the problem requirement is different and so the solution has to be accordingly.

Comment: I am opinionated in this case: I think the requirements need to be reviewed @kinersha, to conform to some sort of **"principle of least astonishment"**! You'll be grateful for it if you are the traveler the OP mentions!

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether `data[i] > data[i - 1] and data[i] > data[i + 1]` and increase counter if `True`.

```
def get_peak_count(data):
    count = 0
    l = len(data)
    for i in range(1, l - 1):
        if data[i - 1] < data[i] and data[i + 1] < data[i]:
            count += 1
    return count

print get_peak_count([1,2,3,2,1])
print get_peak_count([1,2,5,6,4,3,4,2,1])
print get_peak_count([1,2,3,3,2,1])
print get_peak_count([1,2,3,4,5,6,3,1,4,5,7,4,3,12,67,85,34,23])
```

Here is the link where I tested it: https://ideone.com/NNSeDG

Comment: @interjay, you are right! I have updated my answer.

Comment: It would be simpler to just use `range(1, len(data) - 1)`.